# Pandas Dataframe Reshape/Alteration Question

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I feel like this should be an easy solution, but it has eluded me a bit (long week).
Say I have the following Pandas Dataframe (df):

| day | x_count | x_max | y_count | y_max |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 8 | 230 | 18 | 127 |
| 1 | 6 | 174 | 12 | 121 |
| 1 | 5 | 218 | 21 | 184 |
| 1 | 11 | 91 | 32 | 162 |
| 2 | 11 | 128 | 17 | 151 |
| 2 | 13 | 156 | 16 | 148 |
| 2 | 18 | 191 | 22 | 120 |

Etc. How can I collapse it down so that I have one row per day and each of the columns in my example are added across all of their days?

For example:

| day | x_count | x_max | y_count | y_max |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 40 | 713 | 93 | 594 |
| 2 | 42 | 475 | 55 | 419 |

Is it best to reshape it or simply create a new one?

Comment: ``df.groupby('day').sum()``?

Comment: In general, this workflow is called "split-apply-combine". You can read about it here: https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/groupby.html

Comment: Thanks, yeah this was easy. I used the groupby with aggregation. Reading the workflow stuff now.